# Define new position for tooltip in ng2-charts

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

I installed ng2-charts in Angular 6 and i would like to know how to define a new position for tooltip. I found that guide inside Charts.js, but i don't understand where i can define it.
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html

Angular6

```
barChartPlugins = [pluginDataLabels];
chartOptions: any = {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    tooltips: {
     enabled: true,
     position: 'nearest'
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          lineWidth: 0.2
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        },
        gridLines: {
          lineWidth: 0.5
        }
      }]
    },
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        display: false
      },
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define tooltip as a child of `chartOptions` and sibling to `responsive` or 'scales' or `plugins` - you have inserted it in the correct place in your code above... check the example below to see if something else was missing...

relevant **TS**:

```
  public lineChartOptions: any = {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          max: 60,
          min: 0,
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
      }],
    },
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        display: true,
        align: 'top',
        anchor: 'end',
        color: "#222",
        font: {
          family: 'FontAwesome',
          size: 14
        },
      },
      deferred: false
    },
    tooltips: {
      position: 'nearest',
      backgroundColor: 'yellow',
      bodyFontColor: '#999',
      borderColor: '#999',
      borderWidth: 1,
      caretPadding: 15,
      colorBody: '#666',
      displayColors: false,
      enabled: true,
      intersect: true,
      mode: 'x',
      titleFontColor: '#999',
      titleMarginBottom: 10,
      xPadding: 15,
      yPadding: 15,
    }
  };
```

complete [working stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-chart-example-j2wuzm)